# How can I make it so that objects only move with widget / text entry?

Tags: modeling, customization

I constantly move objects / models in tiny increments without noticing. How can I make it so that I can only move objects deliberately! Through widgets or text entry, no accidental mouse dragging!

Comment: Hello! Please don't put that stuff in the title :)

Comment: Don't think it's possible to disable this behavior (called "right mouse button transform"), so you might just have to get used to it... :) (will certainly come with time though!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to not to grab / move objects with <kbd>RMB</kbd>, you should change tweak behaviour.

#### 1. Increase the tweak threshold

To do that increase the *Tweak Threshold* in the User Preferences > Input:

[image]

Set it to something like 100 px. This means the mouse will need to move being right-clicked at least 100px in order this event to happen.

[image]

#### 2. Turn off the tweak event mapping

In the User Preferences search for "tweak". In the results in 3D View section find and turn off `Translate` item with type of event mapping `Tweak` (or change keybinding for it):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Find your outliner. In the outliner are three columns to the far right. The middle of those three columns contains a tiny mouse-pointer glyph. Find your object in the outliner and click that little mouse-pointer glyph. You will find that it toggles on and off. If the glyph is left in the off position, the object will be unresponsive to mouse movements.

Comment: This will disable using the 3D manipulator ("widget") too though, but the transform fields work, so might do the trick after all