# Why can I not select vertices located behind others?

Tags: vertices

When I use <kbd>B</kbd> only the front vertex is selected and not the one behind as well. I have tried turning on and off the *Limit Selection to Visible* and there is no change at all. I have tried all the tricks people have suggested and its still not working.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: "I have tried all the tricks people have suggested and its still not working" - Can you list these so we don't simply re-suggest them? Also, have you tried using wireframe view, toggled with the Z key?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of moving the vertices or just changing the view you can change to *Wireframe* view with the <kbd>Z</kbd> button (by default). Then you can select *all* vertices hidden by faces, edges or other vertices. I use the <kbd>Z</kbd> key a lot since sometimes two vertices are in the exact same position.

Answer (score 1):

how about moving the front vertex on an axis a set distance, manipulate the back vertex and move the front vertex back again.

select front vertex -> <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> -> select back vertex and move it -> select front vertex again -> <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>

instead of x you can of course also use y or z and instead of 1 and -1 you can use 0.1 -0.1 or any other value

Comment: You can simply hide vertices in the foreground either with `H`, or **Mask** modifier or `Alt`+`B` (*Clipping Border*).

Answer (score 1):

When one vertex obscures another in the current viewport, there are two techniques I have found useful for selecting the one behind. One is to modify the view slightly, for example, shifing the viewport a bit to one side, so that both vertices are visible. Then I can select the one I want, and after making the selection return the viewport to the original orientation, if desired. Another technique that sometimes works is to select a second time. Often the first selection event selects one of the vertices, and a second selection at the same place toggles to select the other.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out why this happens!  "B" bound select *does* select the behind vertices as well just like you expect.  After you have selected them DO NOT LEFT CLICK to start the grab/move operation!  This will DESELECT some of the vertices and you will experience your problem.  Instead, select your vertices, then press G to activate grab/move, and move your mouse to move the points.  This will work every time.  Blender is a harsh mistress.

Answer (score -1):

I've found a solution. I did not realize you couldn't click <kbd>RMB</kbd> and drag. The solution ended up being to just press <kbd>G</kbd> instead. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: It's possible to grab selection with `RMB`, adjust Tweak event for that in User Prefs. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40150/how-can-i-make-it-so-that-objects-only-move-with-widget-text-entry.