# Prevent selection of vertices through other objects

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

I noticed that you can select vertices through other objects.
Here is an example to show what I mean:

I have a cube partially inside a sphere. When I do a circle select when the back vertex is hidden behind the sphere...
[image]

Both vertices, including the one that was hidden by the object, are selected.
[image]

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

EDIT: I tried the "limit selection to visible" option but it didn't work... I believe this case is different because it is selecting through a *different* object, not just itself.

Comment: enable "limit selection to visible"; https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vNYn.png

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46636/why-can-i-not-select-vertices-located-behind-others

Comment: The fact that you have an object on top of the one you are editing is not relevant. You can only edit the active one.