# Select all vertices within box boundary when in Front view

Tags: vertices

I have seen other posts relating to this but I am posting now because of a specific situation.

I have a Blend file, created by a designer online, that allows me to create radiators using templates and modifiers.

A video was supplied with this showing how to use the objects.

One of the actions was to increase the height of the radiator by moving the top vertices up, thus ensuring that the scale remains correct. Simply using scaling on the object will change the dimensions of the top part of the radiator. Although this is not by much, given my current requirements, this raises an issue I have come across again and again with selecting vertices. I understand the concept of how box selects the visible vertices in Front view and also that Wiremesh would help. However, in this instance, the vertices combination at the top of the model is very complex and I have been unable to select all the vertices so this Move method cannot work as it reduces the model to a bunch of unselected vertices left behind.

The video, however, worked perfectly (on an earlier version of Blender but, nonetheless, perfect). I could not see any sleight of hand and believe the actions were genuine so this suggests either the object was a damn site simpler in construction in the video or Blender could select all vertices in the box on that plane.

There must have either been a means of selecting all vertices in the current plane view in the previous version or I have completely missed something in latest Blender. I have seen similar in other videos but this is the first time I really want to get this to work in my Blender model.

I am unsure about posting where the video is as I do not want to suggest an issue with the supplier as I am sure everything is genuine.

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46636/why-can-i-not-select-vertices-located-behind-others

Comment: It's not wireframe mode that lets you select backfacing vertices, it's X-ray mode. They are two separate modes. The one you want is the button with two interesting squares. Turn that on and you can select all vertices inside the rectangle. Also you can constrain your scale to X, Y or Z by typing "SX", "SY" or "SZ" and inputting a number or moving the mouse and clicking. You can also omit axes from scaling: "S+SHIFT+Z+2.5" (no plusses) scales the object along the X and Y axes by a factor of 2.5 but ignores Z. Also note that you can change the orientation of these axes (global local normal, etc)

Answer (score 0):

The question was answered by the following comment:

> It's not wireframe mode that lets you select backfacing vertices, it's X-ray mode. They are two separate modes. The one you want is the button with two interesting squares. Turn that on and you can select all vertices inside the rectangle. Also you can constrain your scale to X, Y or Z by typing "SX", "SY" or "SZ" and inputting a number or moving the mouse and clicking. You can also omit axes from scaling: "S+SHIFT+Z+2.5" (no plusses) scales the object along the X and Y axes by a factor of 2.5 but ignores Z. Also note that you can change the orientation of these axes (global local normal, etc) – hatinacat2000 Jul 15 at 23:33